# iphone app switching view with a picker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview, picker

is it possible to switch views using a picker and a button?
for instance say i have a picker with various animals and i select frog in the picker and press a button under the picker and it takes me to a view for frogs.
i have been trying to figure this out for the last three days and havent been able to figure anything out.

i would be greatly appreciated if you could help me!!!!

```
 -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row 
  inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
if (row == 1){
    self.view = Cig;
}
}
```

i have tried something like this but resized its not attached to my button.

Comment: what is `Cig`? Do you want to replace the view within the same view controller or do you plan to have a different one?

Answer (score 1):

Are you forgetting to add the frog view?

```
// Assume that you have a contentView that is visible
// and then a frogView to add to it when the button is pressed...
[contentView addSubview:frogView];
```

Comment: no i got that. im more having trouble connecting the button to the picker to go to that view.